# Java bluetooth keyboard

Tags: java, bluetooth, keyboard

I am wondering where to get started if I want to have my java program communicate over bluetooth?

What my overall aim is to write a Java app for my Mac/windows to that allows the laptop to simulate a bluetooth keyboard.  That is, have my laptop connect to an iPhone, etc, and have the iPHone believe it is connected to a bluetooth keyboard.

My research has consisted of two paths both of which have yielded little so any advice is greatly appreciated.

1 I have been trying to work out what libraries/APIs I should use in Java to have it communicate over bluetooth.

2  Trying to find APIs used by keyboard manufacturers i.e. what does a keyboard send and receive to initially pair with a device and secondly send key press events.  Or as I have recently found out key down and key up events.

Thanks

PS I have found a lot of answers talking about having an androide act as a keyboard.  I am wanting a way for my Mac to act as a keyboard (talk over bluetooth).  A solution that also works on Windows would be great but this is not as necessary at the moment.
Thanks again

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?